# my new SAMSUNG S27D850T monitor DVI resolution is only 2048 x 1152

Tags: display, resolution

I have a Samsung S27D850T monitor with native resolution 2560 x 1440.
It is connected to an USB3 based graphics card.
The maximum resolution I can set is only 2048 x 1152.

(My Windows-7 desktop is already is connected to two other Samsung SA850T's that are 2560 X 1400).

Comment: What graphics card are you using? Do you have the latest drivers? What model DVI to USB converter are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a limitation of your USB display card.

For example, the USB/DVI adapter from StarTech like [USB32DVIPRO](https://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/USB-3-to-DVI-VGA-External-Video-Card-Multi-Monitor-Adapter-2048-1152~USB32DVIPRO) supports up to 2048x1152 only as well. It is also specified in [the product brief](http://www.displaylink.com/assets/product_briefs/NR-114825-DS-6-DL-3000_Product_Brief.pdf) of the chipset it uses. You can see in the table on its second page that `DL-3100 / Resolutions up to 2560x1600 (number)` is left blank.

Comment: That was it.  So, I called StarTech (extremely helpful), got product ID, and ordered from Amazon DisplayPort/USB converter.  Thanks, Tom.